# Jquery Clear Inline css

Tags: jquery, css, inline

I have the below JQuery Code and I need to clear the inline css done by this animation

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#panel").hide(); //updated line, removing the #panel ID.

 $('#tab2').toggle(function(){ //adding a toggle function to the #tab
    $("#panel").show();

        $('#ToolsTitleSpan').text("CLOSE TOOLS");

        $('#tab2').stop().animate({right: '225'}, 800, 'swing', function() {});

        $("#panel").stop().animate({right: '72', width: '230px', opacity:0.8}, 800, 'swing', function() {

                $('.contentSideBar').fadeIn('slow');        
  });


},

function(){ //when the #tab is next cliked
 $('#ToolsTitleSpan').text("OPEN TOOLS");

 $('#tab2').stop().animate({right: '-=225'}, 800, 'swing', function() {

            $('.contentSideBar').fadeOut(slow, function() {});
 });

 $('#panel').stop().animate({width:"0", position:'absolute', float: 'right', opacity:0.1}, 800, 'swing');

});  
});
```

Here is the HTML code if needed:

```
<div id="panelKS"> <!--the hidden panel -->
    <div class="contentSideBarKS">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab2KS">
    <span id="ToolsTitleSpanOpenKS">
        <img id="bg" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('/buttons/opentools', 'theme')?>"/>
    </span>
    <span id="ToolsTitleSpanCloseKS">
        <img id="bg" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('/buttons/closetools', 'theme')?>"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Can you tell me how can I clear the Inline css please?

Thanks

Comment: try $('div').removeAttr('style'); where div means element whose style to erase

Comment: Where do I put this code?

Comment: when do you need this removal of css?

Comment: When the panel closes

Comment: then add removeattr() on the close click event

Comment: meaning after changing the text to OPEN TOOLS

Comment: may be..Try to add it there

Comment: I have just tried it now but didn't work

Comment: Ok.. now it worked. What I did is I removed the stop() attribute

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `!important` in your CSS:

```
.test{
    right:800px !important;    
}
```

That code will make your inline css ignored.

Or you can get the attribute `style` of the DOM , using:

```
$("div.test").attr("style","");
```

Or:

```
$("div.test").attr({style : ""});
```

That's yours to use solution which you prefer more.

Comment: the thing is that I don't need the right element css both inline and externally.

Also my other problem is that both google chrome and firefox works fine. But on my Internet Explorer the side panel does not show?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: that's just the example..., the main idea is just use the !important if you want your inline-css ignored.. :)

owhh ok.. i see you already get the answer :)..

Comment: what kind of problem ?..., if the problem is the standard HTML and CSS... don't forget to use the `<!doctype>` tag for standardization of what types of HTML version do you want to use

Comment: I created a panel on the left hand side of a div, but for some reason it isn't showing on the screen. The only time that I can see this panel is when the screen is being refreshed

Comment: hmmmm maybe my solution didn't much help ... but can maybe you could check your CSS... 

if you want to make a panel in the left and the tab in the right

i can suggest you this kind of css : 
`#panelKS{display:inline-block;
          width : 500px;
          background-color:#f0f;
}
   #tab2KS{
    width : 500px;
    background-color:#fa0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
   }
`

sorry for bad formatting... i do the best i can

Comment: hmmm... tried it... Didn't work. I think the problem is with $("#panel").hide(); //updated line, removing the #panel ID.

Comment: so your panel is hidden in the first ?, and what kind of action that make it showing up again ?

Comment: As at first  my panel is hidden. When someone clicks on the image, it should display the panel

Comment: Another thing is that if I remove $("#panel").hide(); //updated line, removing the #panel ID. only once can I click on the image then it stops working. I Really don't like internet explorer

Comment: my suggestion is better you the css for hide / show ....if you need the animation, just use the animation method in jquery :)...

in my experience that will help you to cross browser, even in IE

Comment: even if I do this, the problem still remains that I can only do the animation once; meaning if i press Open Tools and then close it again, and then I press again the open tools, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help your problem, sorry double post (cause of not enough characters)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #panelKS{
                width : 500px;
                background-color:#f0f;
                display:none;
            }
            #tab2KS{
                width : 500px;
                background-color:#fa0;
                display:inline-block;
                position:absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
        <div id="panelKS"> <!--the hidden panel -->
            <div class="contentSideBarKS">
                Testing
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- my assumtion is -->
        <div id="tab2KS">
            <span id="ToolsTitleSpanOpenKS" value="1">
                <img id="bg" src="#" alt="image 1" title="image 1"/>
            </span>


    <span id="ToolsTitleSpanCloseKS" value="2">
            <img id="bg" src="#" alt="image 2" title="image 2"/>
        </span>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#tab2KS").children().click(function(){
            $("#panelKS").css({display:"inline-block"});
            //after that in your css you could set transparency to 0 and do the animation
        });
    </script>
<body>
```